# Is there a term I can use for "Handy things to know"

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm currently doing coursework for one of my subjects and I am building an application to assist a student in memorising certain things within Maths that give them an advantageous edge in exams. The issue I am having is within my write up I can't seem to find anything better to say rather than "Helping students remember handy things for the exam". Any term or phrase that can say this in short or in a better sounding way would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: An exam study aid? An electronic cheatsheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Enchiridion** is a formal word for a single page, or a small booklet, with essential information.

> Oxford Dictionaries, [definition and pronunciation](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/enchiridion). Etymology
>   Greek (-chir- =hand : hand-sized)

The Wellcome collection has a Physician's Enchiridion on a single folded parchmnent.

Byrhtferth's Enchiridion (there are several copies) is an English medieval diagram comparing the Seasons of the Year, with Child> Youth> Adult> Elder in people, and with the Elements (Earth Air Fire Water). The Microcosm/ Macrocosm principle was an attempt to find some order and structure to knowledge and experience.

[image: Byrhtferth's Enchiridion]

Answer (score 0):

A *mnemonic* is something that is

> 1 : assisting or intended to assist memory
>   \ To distinguish "principal" from "principle" use the mnemonic aid "the principal is your pal."

<sub>(source: [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mnemonic))</sub>

It can be used as a noun or an adjective, but it refers to a single 'handy thing', so you probably need the plural.

There's also the idiom *cheat sheet* which is also used without the intention of actually cheating on the exam.

> 2 : a written or graphic aid (such as a sheet of notes) that can be referred to for help in understanding or remembering something complex

<sub>(source: [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cheat%20sheet))</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I actually started using 'cheat sheet' as a way to describe how these students are learning certain things but I am still left with the issue that may just be me but it still sounds informal. But until I find an alternative I will have to make do :).